# Separate two gestures from being executed at the same time in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I have a real problem with gestures manipulation in Windows 8.1 store apps, I'm building an application where I'm implementing two gestures :

1. Pinch To Zoom.
2. Swiping.

For Pinch To Zoom I use ManipulationStarted -> ManipulationDelta -> ManipulationCompleted
For Swiping I use PointerPressed -> PointerMoved -> PointerReleased

The problem is that when ManipulationStarted fires when attempting to do a PinchToZoom operation, the PointerPressed events fires too ! and cuz the other gesture to perform too !

I can figure out the best manner to separate these to gestures, what's the best practice to do so, I should be missing something about the gestures mechanism.

Comment: I've edited your question, see why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **OnManipulationDelta** method to work with zoom and swiping.

**XAML**

```
<Canvas >
  <Image  ManipulationMode='All'
          Source='Assets/grapes.png'
          Canvas.Top='79'
          Canvas.Left='107'>
    <Image.RenderTransform>
       <CompositeTransform  />
    </Image.RenderTransform>
  </Image>

  <Image  ManipulationMode='All'
          Source='Assets/grapesBW.png'
          Canvas.Top='79'
          Canvas.Left='461'>
    <Image.RenderTransform>
    <CompositeTransform />
   </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
<Rectangle Fill='#7FFFAAAB'
           Height='100'
           Canvas.Left='107'
           Stroke='Black'
           Canvas.Top='335'
           Width='300' />
<Rectangle Fill='#7F738D01'
           Height='100'
           Canvas.Left='461'
           Stroke='Black'
           Canvas.Top='335'
           Width='300' />
</Canvas>
```

**Code**

```
// override the OnManipulationDelta method, instead of setting up event procedures

protected override void OnManipulationDelta(ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs args)
{
    // All the Image elements have ManipulationMode = All enabled
    // The other elements on the page have manipulations disabled
    // therefore the OriginalSource can only be an image, no need to test for null

    var currentImage = args.OriginalSource as Image;
    var transform = currentImage.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;

    transform.TranslateX += args.Delta.Translation.X;
    transform.TranslateY += args.Delta.Translation.Y;

    transform.ScaleX *= args.Delta.Scale;
    transform.ScaleY *= args.Delta.Scale;

    transform.Rotation += args.Delta.Rotation;

base.OnManipulationDelta(args);
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't provide code, I'm guessing how you implemented your Manipulation events.

If you are using the [GestureRecognizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.gesturerecognizer.aspx) class it can also track swipes with the **Dragging** event handler.

GestureRecognizer knows what type of gesture is currently being expressed by the user.

Comment: I'm not using GestureRecognize, I'm using the normal ManipulationStarted/Delta/Completed associated events with the Object for the pinch to zoom, and the Pointer events for swiping

Comment: I suggest taking a look at GestureRecognizer then. It consolidates the code you are writing, and will discern whether the user is swiping or Pinching.

Comment: Well, I have thought about that, but couldn't dive into them, I didn't know what's the difference between using Manipulation Events of the object its self and using Manipulation events of the GestureRecognizer